# Video streaming from file system

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to make a video server, my scenario is users will upload there files and I have a screen that will play all the files of the day like advertisement that we usually watch in our televisions.

So far I have achieved .hls and .flv streaming through node media server.

I have found the best way to stream a file is through FFMPEG, but I am unable to stream multiple files on same output url for example localhost:8000/index.m3u8, Can any one suggest me the right way to stream the next file when FFMPEG ends streaming of a previous file.

Thanks in advance. :)

My node media service config

```
{
  rtmp: {
    port: 1935,
    chunk_size: 60000,
    gop_cache: true,
    ping: 30,
    ping_timeout: 60
  },
  http: {
    port: 8000,
    mediaroot: './media',
    allow_origin: '*'
  },
  trans: {
    ffmpeg: 'E:/Red Matrix/node-stream-master/node-stream-master/usr/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
    tasks: [
      {
        app: 'live',
        hls: true,
        hlsFlags: '[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3:hls_flags=delete_segments]',
        dash: true,
        dashFlags: '[f=dash:window_size=3:extra_window_size=5]'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

FFMPEG stream function

```
function ffmpegStream(stream){

  var proc = ffmpeg()
  .input('D:/Videos/1.MP4')
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function (e) {

      console.log('Processing end !' + JSON.stringify(this));

       ffmpegStream('D:/Videos/2.MP4')
    })
    .on('done', function() {
      console.log('Processing finished !');

    })
    .save('./media/live/abc/index.m3u8');
}
```

Comment: Could you add some examples of code you've already tried? It's hard to say what the issue really is otherwise

Comment: Please check now

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/692990/use-ffmpeg-copy-codec-to-combine-ts-files-into-a-single-mp4  : concat the respective .ts segments ... in effect use the m3u8 container as a shell for concatenation....  may require resizing orig video to normalize HxW